# Can void pointer store the address of class object in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, void

I am new to C++ please tell me is it possible to store class address in void pointer?

Comment: There are no class objects in C++. Classes are not objects in C++.

Comment: How you thinking to do this .. can you please specify your idea(c++ sample code)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: The standard disagrees with you (about the former, not the latter).

Comment: @Benjamin: you mean, standard does not require class objects not to exist?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: I mean, the standard specifically refers to "class objects", many times.

Comment: @Benjamin: interesting, I didn't know that. Can you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: A class object, in this context, is an object who's type is a class or struct or union. Not an object representing a class.

Comment: @Benjamin: thanks, good to know.

Comment: @SunilSingh: There was no reason to change your original wording, unless you really did mean what GingerPlusPlus thought you meant by "class object", (an object which represents a class), rather than what I think you meant (an object who's type is a class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, very simply.

```
class some_class {
public:
    int Member;
};

void Function() {
    some_class SomeObject;
    void* voidPointer = &SomeObject;
}
```

In order to use members of that object though, you need to convert the pointer back to the correct type, and that requires a cast.

```
voidPointer->Member = 10;    // This line is an error

some_class* SomePointer = static_cast<some_class*>(voidPointer);
SomePointer->Member = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.

Comment: To be clear: this stores the address of `SomeObject`, not `some_class`.

Answer (score 3):

No. C++ classes are types, not objects. They don't have any location in memory.

(The functions in a class, and possibly the vtable for a class, do exist in memory, but there's no single location that's treated as representing the class.)